# Where can I download ColdFusion MX 6 or 6.1?

Tags: coldfusion

I know there old and everything, and I already have Coldfusion 8, but I found a great hosting deal and need Coldfusion mx6.1 for it - deos anyone have a link to a place where i can download it?

Comment: surely either the host provides it, or you have a vps and you can install any version you like?

Comment: no, its not illegal, there is a users addition that is free - just new versions and some other editions costs money.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion mx 6.1 windows IS available form FigLeaf, they were given permission to host the downlaod from Adobe. From an old mailing list post I've have stored for prosperity.

> Fig Leaf Software has been authorized by Adobe to provide older releases of
>   CF upon request:
>   http://www.figleaf.com/download/coldfusion-61-win.exe

hth,

john.
UPDATE 19/01/2012 - The above link is still active!

Comment: download link is broken. page not found :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have good *hosting* deal and want cheap (or free) CFML engine, why wouldn't you try the [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free CFML engine, then [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org) is definitely the way to go!  I've had it running on my server for about a year now and love it!

Answer (score 0):

Official Coldfusion 6 is no longer downloadable from Adobe and support is discontinued.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402091.html

There is no free edition of Coldfusion which can be used for business.  Coldfusion 9 has a free educational version for universities as well as a developer's edition which can be used for up to two (2) ip addresses.